# how to pass an array/json values to a select on an angularjs modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, modal-dialog

I'm pretty sure this is very simple problem to solve, but I'm stuck. I have a modal angularjs which opens a form which has a Select element and others which needs to be populated using Array/JSON values. For some how, I am stuck passing these values from either the ModalForm controller, or main page controller. I have created this Plunker which recreates the problem.

The main page code is:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function($uibModal, $log, $document) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;

  $ctrl.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'rostaDetail.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
      $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function() {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };


});

// Please note that $uibModalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $uibModal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($uibModalInstance, items) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = items;
  $ctrl.selected = {
    item: $ctrl.items[0]
  };

  $ctrl.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="example.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl as $ctrl" class="modal-demo">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$ctrl.open()">Open me!</button>
  <div ng-show="$ctrl.selected">Selection from a modal: {{ $ctrl.selected }}</div>
  <div class="modal-parent">
  </div>
</div>
```

Open me!
    Selection from a modal: {{ $ctrl.selected }}

And the modal form is:

```html
<!-- .Modal Form Edit Rosta -->

<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Edit Roster</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectDuty">Select Duty</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="selectDuty" name="selectDuty" ng-model="item" ng-options='item in items' class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="checkboxes">Multiple Checkboxes</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label for="checkboxes-0">
                      <input name="checkboxes" id="checkboxes-0" value="1" type="checkbox">
                      Option one
                    </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <!-- Button (Double) -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button1id">Double Button</label> -->
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <button id="buttonSave" name="buttonSave" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">Save</button>
                        <button id="buttonDelete" name="buttonDelete" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="$ctrl.delete()" ng-show="false">Delete</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-basic" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/M3McgWiHNosxZP8ajidw?p=gitter

Comment: Here's a solved plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/VwRVSXPVeYePdPSpk1vK?p=preview. @hadi already answered before me.

Answer (score 0):

As you used `controllerAs` syntax so for access objects or functions in scope you should use `controllerAs` variable and `.` . here `$ctrl`.

It should be like this.

```
 ng-options='item as item for item in $ctrl.items'
```

and in controller:

```
 $ctrl.ok = function () {
   $ctrl.selected = {
      item: $ctrl.item
   };
  $uibModalInstance.close($ctrl.selected.item);
};
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/l2Bn0arCaYpBWZ0nBEFC?p=preview)